# Multiple users, events, and dates database structure problem

Tags: mysql

I am wandering how should I design the database according to this requirements.
I have:

- multiple users with calendars
- multiple events for one date
- one event can be assign to many dates
- to each event is assign only one person (different than user this event belongs)

I would like to easily have access to all events for a particular date for specific user and also have access to get all dates for the specific event for the same user. Would be also perfect if I could get all events for which a given person is assigned.

I was thinking of creating Date table and Event table with userId and Dates columns and store all datesId for specific event but it won't be easy to get all user events for certain date and person.

Second idea was to create Date table and keep all information in one column for specific date in JSON format, something like:

> user1:{event1, person1, event2, person2}, user2:{event3, person3, event4, person4}

But in this approach there will be difficult to get all dates for certain event and also for person.

Another idea was to create different calendar table for each user but this seems to be very inefficient and I guess problematic when adding new users.

Is there any good approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: you do have m:n and 1:n relations. For each m:n, you need a table. for 1:n, you can work with primary and foreign-keys. First you will need to build you database structure. Then you are going to fill and work with it.

Comment: *"keep all information in one column for specific date in JSON format"* Nope this is a bad idea

Comment: I would give a try to the [Merise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise) method